# Post variable lost on online server, works fine locally

Tags: html, forms

My `post` variables get lost on my online page (works fine locally using the exact same code). Here's how I retrieve them when page reloads:

```
if ( isset($_POST['sub']) ) $sub = $_POST['sub']; else $sub = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_nom']) ) $contact_nom = $_POST['contact_nom']; else $contact_nom = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_prenom']) ) $contact_prenom = $_POST['contact_prenom' ]; else $contact_prenom = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_mail']) ) $contact_mail = $_POST['contact_mail']; else $contact_mail = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_sujet']) ) $contact_sujet = $_POST['contact_sujet']; else $contact_sujet = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_destinataire']) ) $contact_destinataire = $_POST['contact_destinataire']; else $contact_destinataire = ''; 
if ( isset($_POST['contact_message']) ) $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message']; else $contact_message = '';
```

Here's my form:

```
<form id='contact_form_mmt' action='<?php echo bloginfo("wpurl"); ?>/contact' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='contact_nom' placeholder='Votre nom *' data-validation='length' data-validation-length='min3' data-validation-error-msg='<?php echo $text_too_short_or_empty; ?>'>  
  <input type='text' name='contact_prenom' placeholder='Votre prénom *' data-validation='length' data-validation-length='min3' data-validation-error-msg='<?php echo $text_too_short_or_empty; ?>'>
  <input type='text' name='contact_mail' placeholder='Votre mail *' data-validation='email' data-validation-length='min3' data-validation-error-msg='<?php echo $email_valid; ?>'>
  <select name='contact_destinataire'>
    <option value="contact@example.com|Information générales">Information générales</option>
    <option value="webmaster@example.fr|Problèmes liés au site">Problèmes liés au site</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name='contact_message' placeholder='Message *'data-validation='length' data-validation-length='min3' data-validation-error-msg='<?php echo $text_too_short_or_empty; ?>'></textarea>  
  <input type='hidden' name='sub' value='1'>  
  <input type='submit' value='envoyer'>
</form>
```

All of these variables (like `$sub` or `$contact_nom`) are populated on page reload on my local server. They're empty on my local server. Why does this issue happen and how to fix it?

[EDIT] here's the content of htaccess, could the problem be there?

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.fr$
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.example.fr/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have a redirect from www to without or viceversa in your htaccess perhaps? This can cause your post to be empty

Comment: Have a look at the value of `bloginfo("wpurl")`. Check that when you visit that url, you aren't redirected. Try removing the action altogether (If the current page should be the action)

Comment: @ChrisLear, but if redirection was the issue, it should be breaking on his local as well.

Comment: It depends what his local wordpress setup looks like. `bloginfo("wpurl")` returns a value from the wordpress database, and it must be different on the local installation.

Comment: No redirect, and after testing it I see that bloginfo("wpurl") returns the right URL..

Comment: For the love of god, look into ternary operators, please. That just hurts my eyes. (A ternary operator will change the if/else to this: `$sub = (isset($_POST['sub']) ? $_POST['sub'] : '');` - much cleaner for such a list of assignments.

Comment: If you try to `vardump` the `$_POST` variable did you get what you expect?

Comment: Do you have the same configuration in both environmentes? Is there any proxy in your sever ? (ssl terminator, proxy cache, load balancer) Different Php configuration?

Comment: @GabrieleCiech: var_dump($_POST) returns an empty array. Carlos: it's a cheap shared host, probably the same configuration as used on most cheap shared hosting packages. junkfoodjunkie: I'll use that from now onwards, thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see what actually gets posted? Fiddler is a great tool for peeking inside the http traffic between the browser and the server...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to dump `$_POST` on your `index.php` to see if `$_POST` contains values.
If No`($_POST is empty)` so there a redirection in your Wordpress template.
If Yes`($_POST is not empty)` so your `action url` in your form is wrong. And try to track your url where you will use `$_POST`.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) returns an empty array.

Comment: I there was a redirection occuring then the URL I arrive at should be different isn't it? (because it's not)

Comment: if you are getting your parametrs in the same page as the form try to use in your action form $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead of bloginfo("wpurl")